# Export command not working on Client node type DB2

Tags: database, db2

Im currently trying to export some data `EXPORT TO result.csv of DEL SELECT * FROM "DB2BXXXD"."BTTT060" FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY`  from our DB2 z/OS Database server but it returns me the error **The remote database environment does not support the command or one of the command options** . I've been looking in the docs but I don't seem to find the reason. Is this because i'm using a node type: **Client** ? I tried to check if it has anything to do with privileges but when I try to check them with `SELECT AUTHID, PRIVILEGE, OBJECTNAME, OBJECTSCHEMA, OBJECTTYPE FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES` i get the return `SQL0204N  "SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704` is this because the node type is client and it does not see the admin level tables ?

I am able to just run the select statement without any issue and it outputs information.

**Config file**

```
          Database Manager Configuration

     Node type = Client

 Database manager configuration release level            = 0x1000

 Federated Database System Support           (FEDERATED) = NO
 Transaction processor monitor name        (TP_MON_NAME) =

 Default charge-back account           (DFT_ACCOUNT_STR) =

 Java Development Kit installation path       (JDK_PATH) = D:\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk

 Diagnostic error capture level              (DIAGLEVEL) = 3
 Notify Level                              (NOTIFYLEVEL) = 3
 Diagnostic data directory path               (DIAGPATH) = C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2_VW\
 Current member resolved DIAGPATH                        = C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2_VW\
 Alternate diagnostic data directory path (ALT_DIAGPATH) =
 Current member resolved ALT_DIAGPATH                    =
 Size of rotating db2diag & notify logs (MB)  (DIAGSIZE) = 10

 SYSADM group name                        (SYSADM_GROUP) =
 SYSCTRL group name                      (SYSCTRL_GROUP) =
 SYSMAINT group name                    (SYSMAINT_GROUP) =
 SYSMON group name                        (SYSMON_GROUP) =

 Client Userid-Password Plugin          (CLNT_PW_PLUGIN) =
 Client Kerberos Plugin                (CLNT_KRB_PLUGIN) = IBMkrb5
 Group Plugin                             (GROUP_PLUGIN) =
 GSS Plugin for Local Authorization    (LOCAL_GSSPLUGIN) =
 Server Plugin Mode                    (SRV_PLUGIN_MODE) = UNFENCED
 Server List of GSS Plugins      (SRVCON_GSSPLUGIN_LIST) =
 Server Userid-Password Plugin        (SRVCON_PW_PLUGIN) =
 Server Connection Authentication          (SRVCON_AUTH) = NOT_SPECIFIED
 Cluster manager                                         =

 Database manager authentication        (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER_ENCRYPT
 Cataloging allowed without authority   (CATALOG_NOAUTH) = YES
 Bypass federated authentication            (FED_NOAUTH) = NO

 Java Virtual Machine heap size (4KB)     (JAVA_HEAP_SZ) = 2048
 Directory cache support                     (DIR_CACHE) = YES

 Max requester I/O block size (bytes)         (RQRIOBLK) = 65535
 Workload impact by throttled utilities(UTIL_IMPACT_LIM) = 10

 Transaction manager database name         (TM_DATABASE) = 1ST_CONN

 Discovery mode                               (DISCOVER) = KNOWN

 SSL client keydb file                  (SSL_CLNT_KEYDB) = C:\DB2SSL\key.kdb
 SSL client stash file                  (SSL_CLNT_STASH) = C:\DB2SSL\key.sth

 db2start/db2stop timeout (min)        (START_STOP_TIME) = 0

 WLM dispatcher enabled                 (WLM_DISPATCHER) = NO
 WLM dispatcher concurrency            (WLM_DISP_CONCUR) = COMPUTED
 WLM dispatcher CPU shares enabled (WLM_DISP_CPU_SHARES) = NO
 WLM dispatcher min. utilization (%) (WLM_DISP_MIN_UTIL) = 5

 Communication buffer exit library list (COMM_EXIT_LIST) =
 Current effective arch level         (CUR_EFF_ARCH_LVL) = V:10 R:5 M:0 F:10 I:0 SB:0
 Current effective code level         (CUR_EFF_CODE_LVL) = V:10 R:5 M:0 F:10 I:0 SB:0
```

**All tips more than welcome !!**

Comment: It looks like PowerShell is incidental to your problem, so I suggest removing the tag. If it isn't incidental, please show any relevant PowerShell commands that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use csv (DELimited) files to export from / import to Db2 for z/OS or IBM i using them.
[Moving data with Db2 Connect](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=options-moving-data-db2-connect):

> With Db2 Connect, export and import operations must meet the following conditions:
>
> - **The file type must be PC/IXF.**
>   ...